# Print a newline in a php array with JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, newline

I have been looking on how to print a new line in a php array. When I echo the data it comes like this:

`Data Criação do Registo - 2014-12-23Bloco Operatório - TrueTipo de Internamento - UrgenteTipo de Internamento Cirurgia - com cirurgiaGlasgow Hospital - 15 (O-4 V-5 M-6)`

I want it  to look like this, but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

```
Data Criação do Registo - 2014-12-23
Bloco Operatório - True
Tipo de Internamento - Urgente
Tipo de Internamento Cirurgia - com cirurgia
Glasgow Hospital - 15 (O-4 V-5 M-6)
```

This is my code:

```
$query1 = "SELECT TO_CHAR(DATACRIACAO,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS DATACRIACAO, NPROCESSO, BLOCOOPERATORIO, TIPOINTERNAMENTO, TIPOINTERNAMENTOCIRURGIA, GLASGOW_HOSPITAL 
FROM PATIENT_TIMELINE_ADMISSAO WHERE NPROCESSO =629844";

$result1 = oci_parse($connect, $query1);
oci_execute($result1);

while($res1 = oci_fetch_array($result1)) {
 $infotimeline['description']= 'Data Criação do Registo - '.$res1['DATACRIACAO'].
 'Bloco Operatório - '.$res1['BLOCOOPERATORIO'].'Tipo de Internamento - '.$res1['TIPOINTERNAMENTO'].
 'Tipo de Internamento Cirurgia - '.$res1['TIPOINTERNAMENTOCIRURGIA'].
 'Glasgow Hospital - '.$res1['GLASGOW_HOSPITAL'];
}
$data = str_replace(array('[', ']','{','}'), '', htmlspecialchars(json_encode($infotimeline), ENT_NOQUOTES));
echo $data;
```

EDIT: I'm also adding that this code is in `pptimeline.php` file and I have this as header `header('Content-Type: application/json');` making to be a json file. Then the info is printed in my `basic.php` file which has this on top `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

I'm also adding the full code in case it helps - [pptimeline](http://collabedit.com/k646h) and [basic.php](http://collabedit.com/gkbtr)

Comment: You would use `"<br />\n"` (an HTML newline as well as a textual newline) where ever you want the line break to be.

Comment: not really. in php if you want t new line you need to echo "\n"; this is old, this also exists in perl i think. if you want a retun you'd echo "\r", if you wanted a tab you'd echo "\t";

Comment: if you're in a browser, then use `<br>`. browsers don't understand or care what `\n` is, unless they're rendering in text mode. html has no line breaks other than `<br>`.

Comment: At the time of saving this text try to save it with new line.

Comment: `nl2br` is designed for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone runs into a similiar issue this is how I solved it. I reworked the code and somehow it prints the new line like this.

```
$query1 = "SELECT TO_CHAR(DATACRIACAO,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS DATACRIACAO, NPROCESSO, BLOCOOPERATORIO, TIPOINTERNAMENTO, TIPOINTERNAMENTOCIRURGIA, GLASGOW_HOSPITAL 
FROM PATIENT_TIMELINE_ADMISSAO WHERE NPROCESSO =".$nprocesso."";

$result1 = oci_parse($connect, $query1);
oci_execute($result1);

while($infotimeline = oci_fetch_array($result1)) 
    {
        $timel[] = $infotimeline;
    }
foreach ($timel as $infotimeline){
$data =
'"id":"pptimeline"'.','.
'"title":"Pervasive Patient Timeline - Doente nº '.$infotimeline["NPROCESSO"].'"'.','.
'"description":"'.'<p>'.'Data Criação do Registo - '.$infotimeline["DATACRIACAO"].'</p>'.
'<p>'.'Bloco Operatório - '.$infotimeline['BLOCOOPERATORIO'].'</p>'.
'<p>'.'Tipo de Internamento Cirurgia - '.$infotimeline['TIPOINTERNAMENTOCIRURGIA'].'</p>'.
'<p>'.'Glasgow Hospital - '.$infotimeline['GLASGOW_HOSPITAL'].'</p>'.'"'.','.
'"focus_date":"2015-02-20"'.','.
'"initial_zoom":10'
;
}
echo $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code of lines :

```
while($res1 = oci_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $infotimeline['description'] = 'Data Criação do Registo -          '.$res1['DATACRIACAO']. '<br/>'.
    'Bloco Operatório - '.$res1['BLOCOOPERATORIO'].'Tipo de Internamento -     '.$res1['TIPOINTERNAMENTO'].'<br/>'.
    'Tipo de Internamento Cirurgia - '.$res1['TIPOINTERNAMENTOCIRURGIA'].'<br/>'.
    'Glasgow Hospital - '.$res1['GLASGOW_HOSPITAL'];
}
$data = str_replace(array('[', ']','{','}'), '', htmlspecialchars(json_encode($infotimeline), ENT_NOQUOTES));
echo $data;
```

Comment: I tried what you said to no avail, it still doesn't appear in a new line. This is what it looks like: `Data Criação do Registo - 2014-12-23<br/>Bloco Operatório - True<br/>Tipo de Internamento - Urgente<br/>Tipo de Internamento Cirurgia - com cirurgia<br/>Glasgow Hospital - 15 (O-4 V-5 M-6)`

Answer (score 0):

User `<br>` between each of the lines you want to print out: ie.

```
'Data Criação do Registo - '.$res1['DATACRIACAO'].
 '<br>Bloco Operatório - '.$res1['BLOCOOPERATORIO'].'<br>Tipo de Internamento - '.$res1['TIPOINTERNAMENTO'].
 '<br>Tipo de Internamento Cirurgia - '.$res1['TIPOINTERNAMENTOCIRURGIA'].
 '<br>Glasgow Hospital - '.$res1['GLASGOW_HOSPITAL'];
```

Comment: I already tried that and it came out like this: `<br>Data Criação do Registo - 2014-12-23<br>Bloco Operatório - True<br>Tipo de Internamento - Urgente<br>Tipo de Internamento Cirurgia - com cirurgia<br>Glasgow Hospital - 15 (O-4 V-5 M-6)`

Comment: Have you added a HTML doctype?

Comment: The code I presented in my question is in `pptimeline.php` file and I have this as header `header('Content-Type: application/json');` making to be a json file. Then the info is printed in my `basic.php` file  which has this on top `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Answer (score 0):

First: you need to format your string as you need - just insert linefeeds. `"\n"`
Second: To show all of this in the browser - use `nl2br`, which convert all linefeeds to `<br/>` tag.
You should do it **after** you escape html entities.

```
$query1 = "SELECT TO_CHAR(DATACRIACAO,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS DATACRIACAO, NPROCESSO, BLOCOOPERATORIO, TIPOINTERNAMENTO, TIPOINTERNAMENTOCIRURGIA, GLASGOW_HOSPITAL 
FROM PATIENT_TIMELINE_ADMISSAO WHERE NPROCESSO =629844";

$result1 = oci_parse($connect, $query1);
oci_execute($result1);

while($res1 = oci_fetch_array($result1)) {
 $infotimeline['description']= 
 'Data Criação do Registo - '.$res1['DATACRIACAO']."\n".
 'Bloco Operatório - '.$res1['BLOCOOPERATORIO']."\n".
'Tipo de Internamento - '.$res1['TIPOINTERNAMENTO']."\n".
 'Tipo de Internamento Ciru - '.$res1['TIPOINTERNAMENTOCIRURGIA']."\n".
 'Glasgow Hospital - '.$res1['GLASGOW_HOSPITAL'];
}
$data = str_replace(array('[', ']','{','}'), '', htmlspecialchars(json_encode($infotimeline), ENT_NOQUOTES));
$data = nl2br($data);
echo $data;
```

Comment: I added what you said but it is still not working, although I checked inspect element and it appeared in new lines - [here](http://gyazo.com/a4a42659e74079083ae5d957b376c354). I tried in different browsers and still the same. I really don't get it. However if I try to add `<br />` by myself in the inspect element it goes into a new line, so it is some weird problem in the code.

Comment: Are you sure, that you don't miss `nl2br` row? http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: Yes, I rechecked  and everything is like the code you showed me, but it still doens't work. It just adds a space instead of breaking into a new line.